# Find file in source directory in emacs lisp

Tags: file, emacs, path, elisp

I have a text file containing a list of words that my elisp code is dependent on. I would like to keep it in the same directory as the source files.

Using a relative path does not seem to work, because when the function that triggers the reading is run the path is relative to what buffer you are currently in.

The code:

```
(defconst etype-lines-file "etype.lines")

(defun etype-read-file ()
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents (expand-file-name etype-lines-file default-directory))
    (apply
     'vector
     (split-string
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)) "\n"))))
```

Any way to achieve a path relative to the location of the source code file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `load-file-name` for this.  While an Emacs Lisp file is being compiled or loaded, it's bound to the name of the source file.  Here is an example from the elisp manual:

```
 (defconst superfrobnicator-base (file-name-directory load-file-name))

 (defun superfrobnicator-fetch-image (file)
   (expand-file-name file superfrobnicator-base))
```

That means that you'll have to load your file by `load-file` or `emacs-lisp-byte-compile-and-load` exclusively, instead of evaluating parts of the buffer, since `load-file-name` is `nil` in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, because of this code:

`(insert-file-contents (expand-file-name etype-lines-file` ***`default-directory`***))`

Instead, either pass the directory you want to your function, as an argument, and use that here, in place of `default-directory`, or use a global variable (or "constant", via `defconst`) for the directory (in place of `default-directory` here).